# How to troubleshoot ORA-43856: Unsupported LOB type for SECUREFILE LOB operation

Tags: oracle, blob

Depending on the Oracle server I'm talking to, the same create table DDL statement can succeed or fail:

On Server#1

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table h5basic (b blob) lob(b) store as basicfile;
Table created.

SQL> create table h5basic$none (b blob) lob(b) store as basicfile (retention none);
create table h5basic$none (b blob) lob(b) store as basicfile (retention none)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-43856: Unsupported LOB type for SECUREFILE LOB operation
```

On Server#2

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table h5basic (b blob) lob(b) store as basicfile;
Table created.

SQL> create table h5basic$none (b blob) lob(b) store as basicfile (retention none);
Table created.
```

The two servers are not exactly the same version, and the first runs on Linux while the second on Windows, but appart from that, what could be different between the two to explain this difference in behavior? Thanks for any tips in troubleshooting this issue. --DD

Answer (score 2):

Some options are:

1. Check the `init.ora` file to see if the `db_securefile` parameter is set differently - allowable values are: `{ ALWAYS | FORCE | PERMITTED | NEVER | IGNORE }` (See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_smart.htm#BABJFEBB) for more details).
2. Check if the tablespaces are both ASSM as (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_smart.htm#ADLOB4444)): A SecureFile can only be created in an automatic segment space management (ASSM) tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow the solution that worked for me :

**sqlplus / as sysdba**

**sql> alter system set db_securefile='PERMITTED';**