# Why dbms_lob.fragment_insert is not working in my script?

Tags: plsql

Simple table with blob column.

```
create table table01 (
  myCode  VARCHAR2(10),
  myValue blob
);

insert into table01(myCode, myValue) values('abc', hextoraw('414243'));
```

I'm trying to modify blob value using dbms_lob.fragment_insert

```
declare
  l_b BLOB;
begin
  SELECT myValue
  INTO l_b
  FROM table01
  WHERE myCode = 'abc'
  FOR UPDATE;

  dbms_lob.fragment_insert(l_b, 3, 1+dbms_lob.getlength(l_b), hextoraw('787878'));
end;
/
```

and I see exception like below

```
declare
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-43856: Unsupported LOB type for SECUREFILE LOB operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 1159
ORA-06512: at line 10  
43856. 0000 -  "Unsupported LOB type for SECUREFILE LOB operation"
Document: YES
Cause:    A LOB that is not a SECUREFILE was used in a SQL statement or
          in a call where a SECUREFILE LOB was expected.
Action:   Convert the LOB to a SECUREFILE LOB or do not use this keyword
          or call.
```

My knowledge about Oracle DB is not sufficient to understand what I'm doing wrong. Is it possible to use dbms_lob.fragment_insert in the way I tried to ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to troubleshoot ORA-43856: Unsupported LOB type for SECUREFILE LOB operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432573/how-to-troubleshoot-ora-43856-unsupported-lob-type-for-securefile-lob-operation)

Comment: Thank you for linked question. It's loosely connected with mine. I've answered to my question myself

Answer (score 0):

The answer for my question probably is that dbms_lob.fragment_insert cannot be used to modify blobs which are not stored as a securefiles :(.

When I create my table in following way

```
create table table01 (
  myCode  VARCHAR2(10),
  myValue blob
) lob(myValue) store as SECUREFILE;
```

my script works.

Saddly I'm searching pl/sql solution to modify big blobs without access to database host filesystem and with blobs stored as not a securefiles. I thought that dbms_lob.fragment_insert could be a solution